# Pandas - Splitting columns to separate positive and negative numbers

Tags: pandas, split, calculated-columns

I have a dataframe in which there are a number of columns containing numerical data. Both positive and negative numbers are found in every column but I want to separate them into their own set of columns. 
Currently, the dataframe looks like this:

```
0    Col1    Col2    Col3
1    55      43      98
2    -20     35      88
3    -43     -47     -77
```

I want to modify so it looks like this:

```
0    Col_1A    Col_2A    Col_3A      Col_1B    Col_2B    Col_3B
1    55        43        98          NaN       NaN       NaN       
2    NaN       35        88          -20       NaN       NaN
3    NaN       NaN       NaN         -43       -47       -77
```

I think I can figure out a scripting solution using *lapply* to treat each column's values as an array, copy the negative values to a new column and delete them from the original (which I'll post as an answer if I wind up needing to do that) but this strikes me as a problem that might have a single-command solution. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use boolean masking to select the values of interest, then `concat` them passing `axis=1`, you can then just rename by directly assigning to the `columns` attribute:

```
In [145]:

merged = pd.concat([df[df>=0], df[df<0]], axis=1)
merged.columns = ['Col_1A','Col_2A','Col_3A','Col_1B','Col_2B','Col_3B']
merged
Out[145]:
   Col_1A  Col_2A  Col_3A  Col_1B  Col_2B  Col_3B
0                                                
1      55      43      98     NaN     NaN     NaN
2     NaN      35      88     -20     NaN     NaN
3     NaN     NaN     NaN     -43     -47     -77
```

Of you can `join` and set the desired suffixes (thanks to @DSM):

```
In [147]:

df[df>=0].join(df[df<0], lsuffix="_A", rsuffix="_B")
Out[147]:
   Col1_A  Col2_A  Col3_A  Col1_B  Col2_B  Col3_B
0                                                
1      55      43      98     NaN     NaN     NaN
2     NaN      35      88     -20     NaN     NaN
3     NaN     NaN     NaN     -43     -47     -77
```

Another way is to `merge` (which is what `join` uses underneath):

```
In [148]:

df[df>=0].merge(df[df<0], left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_A', '_B'))
Out[148]:
   Col1_A  Col2_A  Col3_A  Col1_B  Col2_B  Col3_B
0                                                
1      55      43      98     NaN     NaN     NaN
2     NaN      35      88     -20     NaN     NaN
3     NaN     NaN     NaN     -43     -47     -77
```

Comment: Or `join` instead of `concat`: `df[df>=0].join(df[df<0], lsuffix="A", rsuffix="B")`.